# "Could not load file or assembly" when executing app from Task Runner App

Tags: server, config, .net-assembly, assemblybinding

We have a .NET app that uses a DLL.  The DLL is registered in GAC.  We have a task runner app (ESP from BroadCom) that executes our apps.

- The ESP service on the target server is set up to use local system account with "Allow service to interact with desktop"
- An AD account is passed via the ESP job config to the service to execute the app
- This AD account is an Administrator, has logon as batch, logon as service

When I run the job via my own, individual AD account, RDP'd into the server, it's successful.
When I run the job via the AD service account, RDP'd into the server, it's successful.
When I run the job via ESP using the same AD account, I get "Could not load file or assembly".

We reached out to the vendor and sent logs -- ESP is executing the application successfully, but when the .NET app runs via ESP, it cannot find the DLL.

It's not a perm issue, since I can log in using the account and execute manually, no problem.

My suspicion is it is an environment/server config issue but we have been beating our head against this for a month and I have no leads.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using [Fusion Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer)? If so, adding its outputs in the good cases and the bad case, may provide clues.